# Executing controller action from Actor in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I want an Akka Actor scheduled to execute some controller action in Play 2.3. Is there any possiblity to make it without making WS request? I don't want to set application url anywhere in configuration.

Comment: Why not just making a common function that can be used either from a web request or internally from the Actor?

Comment: I want to refresh the cache, the response of action is saved to.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule some action in Akka like this

```
  case object Refresh
  system.scheduler.schedule(5.minutes, 5.minutes, cacheActor, Refresh)
```

In the actor you can handle the Refresh message

```
def receive = {
  case Refresh => {
     //Refresh cache here
  }
  ...
}
```

As for the code in the Play controller, it might be a good idea to move the code in the Play controller to a place both the controller and the actor can access.